# incompatibility issue with chrome 33.0.1750.117 and breeze.js

Tags: google-chrome, breeze

I've found a incompatibility issue between chrome 33.0.1750.117 and breeze.js 1.3.2,  1.3.3, and 1.3.5

before this chrome version worked just fine.

the message that I get is: "Error retreiving data. deferred is not defined"

Does anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: Breeze.js is at v.1.4.8, soon to be v.1.4.9. Unlikely we'd investigate compatibility of such an old version. Hope you can upgrade and tell us if the problem persists.